# Edit value before its being injected in a service

Tags: angularjs

I have app configuration object as a value inside a dependency module.

I want to edit that object inside a dependant module before it's being injected anywhere.

How.

```
dependency.value('sett', {
    bla: 'bla'
});

dependant.config(function (sett) {
    // sett is not available here
});
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/q9D8ZAMn9izBe2mmrIr8?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$provide`:

```
dependant.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.value('sett', { bla: 'not bla' });
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/cEqxrMjro72RADymEgow?p=preview

**Edit:**

If you want to edit a specific value instead of overriding the entire value object you can use the run block:

> **Run blocks** - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>   injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>   configuration during application run time.

```
dependant.run(function (sett) {
  sett.bla = 'not bla';
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/tWT9ZTS47lDj6yZOj5cf?p=preview

Comment: This acts as overwriting the complete object. I just need to edit some attributes in the existing one.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. Updated my answer.

Comment: This is badass. So what u saying is that no service or factory or controller is being run/loaded/instantiated before the run block? Is that what 'Injector being created' means? Simply indexing all the services/factories?

Comment: Yes. Unless you inject a service that depends on sett in the actual run block. But if that is needed you can inject $injector instead and get the service via $injector.get(serviceName) after your modification of sett.